# typescript return property data of interface, return type definition

Tags: typescript

I have an function where I want to query data from an data object structured by an interface.
This function should resolve the property data form the data object. This is working if I have any as return type, however there should be a better approach, where the return type will be the type of the property.

Here is my approach:
[Coding](https://codesandbox.io/s/l3zf6)

[image]

There I only get back an union type of all properties of the interface, however I should get back the type of the property that I want to return.

Comment: You should use the same technique like in typescript playground: a generic that extends `keyof`. Btw, there is a chance you posted the wrong link to playground: it has nothing in common with your code.

Comment: hi, i m not quite sure what you mean, could you please explain further? I clicked on the link it is redirecting to the same code for me at least.

Comment: The Typescript playground saves the last code you've written on the site. **You** see the correct code because that was the last piece of code you've written, but no one else does since your link is not exported correctly.

Comment: All right, i changed it, you should now see the correct code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make `getData` generic and then reuse the generic type for both argument and return value:

```
interface Rofl {
  name:string,
  id:number,
}

const data: Rofl = {
  name:"lol",
  id:1,
};

function getData<T extends keyof Rofl>(property: T): Rofl[T] {
  return data[property];
}


const lol:string = getData("name");
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=29&pln=16&pc=33#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHsYBtkG8CwAUMsiHALYQBcAzmFKAOYA0RJwAJlSAK7kBG0VoQC+RIgnQg6yDnDBwqaTDgC8eNqQrUARFnRYdw9lwCMwkQG5xhGDxAIwwKckYQwAEXlwAPABVkCAAPSBAOGmQAawgAT0xlbAA+AAoAByh0VOgwGKU-AEolDGwAbT8AXQ1iZCh3HigQWW8S9MzsmPLrURsJKRl9LFp6JmR1N09vZJ0ySh18rt7pAwgAOn1GZIH5oA

Comment: that is exactly what i was looking for! thx :)